# React router, inferred query string

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I do realize this might be a bad practice, but I need to redirect a user according to their email in exactly this manner:

`/chat?user={emailAddress}`

What should the exact path look like so that I could access emailAddress as a prop in chatRenderer ? URL must have `name` query in it.

```
   <Route
     exact
     path={`/chat?user=???`}
     render={this.chatRenderer}
   />
```

Comment: Commas, dots and some other characters are allowed in email addresses, but have to be escaped in URLs. So you need to escape (and later, unescape) the email addresses. `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` should do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-router-dom` concerns itself only with matching the path part of the URL.

Change the `Route` to match the URL sans the queryString:

```
<Route
  path="/chat"
  render={this.chatRenderer}
/>
```

In the routed component access the queryString `search` from the [`location`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location) object. `location` is available on `props` if rendered by `render` or `component` prop of `Route`, or can be accessed by the [`useLocation`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

```
const { search } = location;

...

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
const userEmail = searchParams.get('user');

// apply logic against userEmail value
```

Answer (score 0):

**App.js**

```js
<Route
     exact
     path="/chat"
     component={UserChatPage}
   />
```

**Home page**

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyHomePage (){

const history = useHistory()

const redirect = ()=> history.push(`/chat?user=${email}`);
```

**User chat page**

```js
var url_string = window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var user = url.searchParams.get("user");
```